# Erlang store file contents in a list

Tags: binary, erlang

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxzZa.png)

```
read_CNF_File(FileName)->
case file:read_file(FileName) of
{ok, Data} ->  print(binary:split(Data, [<<"\n">>], [global]));
{error, Reason} -> Reason end.

print([]) -> ok;
print([L|List]) ->
    L,
    print(List).
```

[Pic Related] How do I store contents from a file into a list (ideally a list of every line), if I try to io:fwrite As in read_CNF_File it seems to store it the way I want, however once I try to call print with that it just passes As as an empty list, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is your print function that does nothing.

If you pass it à non empty list, it removes the first element (A in your code), the statement `A,` does nothing, and then recursively call itself with the tail of the list, until it is empty a' finally returns OK.

Comment: lol, thank you my stupid brain didn't comprehend that, indeed it works thanks alot :)